# How to send AJAX call only once in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I am confused about how to write this logic. 
What I am looking for is when the video is playing and if the video watched percentage is more than 2% I want to send an AJAX request once. But what is  actually happening is it  will keep on triggering from **2%  to 100%**

If I write **=(equals)** instead of **>(greater than)** it is not triggering because I am not rounding the number so due to decimals it is not triggering. How can I write this logic in this scenario then?
The AJAX request should only send one time.

```
var j = 0;
$("#video").bind("timeupdate", function() {
  var currentTime = this.currentTime;
  var totalPlayed = 0;
  var played = video.played;
  for (var i = 0; i < played.length; i++) {
    totalPlayed += played.end(i) - played.start(i);
    var  playedInPercentage = (totalPlayed/totalTime)*100;
  }
/*here i want to write a logic to send this lowered only once.*/
  if (totalPlayed > 0.02*(totalTime)) { //watched 2% and above then this will excute 0.02(2%)
    alert("asdsad");
    if(j < 1) {
        /* Ajax call  video watched starts here it should trigger only once*/
        $.ajax({
            url: "student_learning_controller.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {'action': 'videoWatched', 'course_id': course_id,'videoId' : videoId,'totalVideoTime':totalTime,'totalPlayedTime':totalPlayed,'percentagePlayed':playedInPercentage },
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (response) {
                if (response["success"] == true) {
                    $("#success_message").html(response["message"]);    

                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#warning_message").show();
                $("#warning_message").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            }
        });
        /* Ajax call  video watched ends here */
    }
    j += 1; //Reset for duplicates (repeated playback)
}
});
```

Comment: Keep a global variable e.g. `var ajaxSent = false;`, and set it to true when you make the ajax call. Now, just add one extra condition above the ajax call that checks that `ajaxSent` variable is not true.

Comment: Just use a boolean flag and set its value over 1st call and check it with a condition to send another call or not

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj can you please write answer i am not getting it.

Comment: Is there some other code surrounding this? It looks like you're calling this code from somewhere else and thus re-initialising the "j" variable back to 0 each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `var triggered = 0;` before the "if".

And then the "if" becomes: `if(totalPlayed > 0.02*(totalTime) && !triggered ){triggered = 1;`

This will be executed just once because when you enter the "if" you will update the "triggered" variable and it won't enter the "if" again.

Comment: It is not working...still ajax call is keep on triggering.

Comment: Put the triggered variable outside of any loops, should work

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable. When you enter ajax, you change the variable. Use the variable within your IF.

JS:

```
var var_tr = $(#hideninput).val();
if(totalPlayed > 0.02*(totalTime) && Var_tr == "false") {
         ...
         $(#hideninput).val("True");
        /* Ajax call  video watched starts here it should trigger only once*/
        $.ajax({
            url: "student_learning_controller.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {'action': 'videoWatched', 'course_id': course_id,'videoId' : videoId,'totalVideoTime':totalTime,'totalPlayedTime':totalPlayed,'percentagePlayed':playedInPercentage },
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (response) {
                if (response["success"] == true) {
                    $("#success_message").html(response["message"]);    

                }
            },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $("#warning_message").show();
            $("#warning_message").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            $(#hideninput).val("false");
        }
    });
    /* Ajax call  video watched ends here */
}
```

HTML create:

```
<input id = "hideninput" type = "hidden" value = "false">
```

Comment: You should update the variable at the start of ajax call. If you put it in success response, then by the time response comes in for first ajax request, several other ajax requests would have fired.