# Get json data only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

if I mouseover on my element 5 times then json data has been loading 5 times but I want when ever I mouseover my element only load json data for one times to.

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.details-checkin,.details-checkout', function() {
  $.getJSON('http://content.anitur.com/web/Assets/js/data.json', function(data) {
    //bla bla blaaa
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send AJAX call only once in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774951/how-to-send-ajax-call-only-once-in-my-case)

Comment: Or [How to call ajax only once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11738859/215552) or [Prevent ajax call from firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26475445/215552)...

Comment: sorry and thank you

Comment: You can attach your event handle with ["jQuery one"](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

This fires your event handle only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a simple check to see if you already made the call. This uses a variable scoped outside the event handler

```
var isLoading = false;
$(document).on('mouseover', '.details-checkin,.details-checkout', function() {
  if(isLoading === false) {
    isLoading = true
    $.getJSON('http://content.anitur.com/web/Assets/js/data.json', function(data) {
      //bla bla blaaa
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @ani_css glad it worked for you, feel free to mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using the sessionStorage? If you need to get JSON only once every session, you could add something like this:

```
sessionStorage.jsonWasRead = 'true';

if (sessionStorage.jsonWasRead != 'true') {
    //your read json code
}
```